# Modal component not working in android

Tags: react-native

I have developed a react-native IOS app. Trying to run that in android using RN-android.

But the modal doesn't seem to be working. Is the modal component supported in android?

The documentation doesn't exclude android support. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not supported in Android yet.
And there's no release schedule for it AFAIK.

You can refer to this issue for more information:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3004#issuecomment-143096687